# Displaying stack linked list in C Issue

Tags: c, list, stack

This is the source code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct Fraction{
    int num;
    int denom;
};

typedef struct Fraction Frac;
typedef Frac* FracPtr;

struct FracNode {
    Frac fr;
    struct FracNode* next;
};

typedef struct FracNode FrNode;
typedef FrNode* FrNodePtr;

struct FracStack {
    int stkSize;
    FrNodePtr frNodePtr;
};

typedef struct FracStack FrStk;
typedef FrStk* FrStkPtr;

FrNodePtr createFrNode(void);
FrStkPtr createFrNodeStk(void);
void pushFrNode(FrStkPtr*, FrNodePtr);
void printStack(FrStkPtr);

int main() {

    FrNodePtr frNodeTmpPtr = 0;
    FrNodePtr frNodeTmpPtr2 = 0;
    FrStkPtr frStkPtr = 0;
    frNodeTmpPtr = createFrNode();
    frStkPtr = createFrNodeStk();
    pushFrNode(&frStkPtr, frNodeTmpPtr);
    printStack(frStkPtr);

    frNodeTmpPtr2 = createFrNode();
    pushFrNode(&frStkPtr, frNodeTmpPtr2);
    printStack(frStkPtr); // Only the newly created fraction is printed. frNodeTmpPtr didn't get printed as part of the stack. Is there an issue with my print function or the push function?

    free (frNodeTmpPtr);
    free (frNodeTmpPtr2);
    free (frStkPtr);
    return 0;
}


//Print Stack
void printStack(FrStkPtr stkPtr) {

    while (stkPtr->frNodePtr != 0) {
        printf("Numerator: %d & Denominator: %d\n\n", stkPtr->frNodePtr->fr.num, stkPtr->frNodePtr->fr.denom);
        stkPtr->frNodePtr = stkPtr->frNodePtr->next;
    }

    return;
}

//Push Node
void pushFrNode(FrStkPtr* stkPtr, FrNodePtr nPtr) {

    if ((*stkPtr)->frNodePtr != 0) {
        nPtr->next = ((*stkPtr))->frNodePtr;
    }

    (*stkPtr)->frNodePtr = nPtr;
    (*stkPtr)->stkSize++;

    return;
}

//Create Stack
FrStkPtr createFrNodeStk() {

    FrStkPtr frStkPtr;
    frStkPtr = (FrStkPtr) malloc (sizeof(FrStk));
    frStkPtr->stkSize = 0;
    frStkPtr->frNodePtr = 0;

    return frStkPtr;
}

//Create Node
FrNodePtr createFrNode() {

    FrNodePtr frNodePtr;
    frNodePtr = (FrNodePtr) malloc (sizeof(FrNode));
    frNodePtr->next = 0;

    printf("Enter the numerator: ");
    scanf("%d", &(frNodePtr->fr.num));

    do {
        printf("\nEnter a non-zero denominator: ");
        scanf("%d", &(frNodePtr->fr.denom));
        if (frNodePtr->fr.denom < 0) {
            frNodePtr->fr.denom = -(frNodePtr->fr.denom);
            frNodePtr->fr.num = -(frNodePtr->fr.num);
        }
    } while (frNodePtr->fr.denom == 0);

    return frNodePtr;
}
```

In main, i created one fraction, pushed it into the created stack. Print it out. Then, i created another fraction, pushed it into the stack and print it. The problem is when i print out the stack it only prints out the last fraction created, not both fractions.

Sample run:

Enter the numerator: 1

Enter a non-zero denominator: 1

Numerator: 1 & Denominator: 1

Enter the numerator: 2

Enter a non-zero denominator: 2

Numerator: 2 & Denominator: 2 //I want this part to print out 1/1 and 2/2 not just 2/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the printing function to the following:

```cpp
//Print Stack
void printStack(FrStkPtr stkPtr) {
    FrNodePtr pointer = stkPtr->frNodePtr;
    while (pointer != 0) {
        printf("Numerator: %d & Denominator: %d\n\n", pointer->fr.num, pointer->fr.denom);
        pointer = pointer->next;
    }
    return;
}
```